# Загрузка spring-boot приложения на github с поддержкой БД

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, github

Предположим я хочу загрузить Spring boot приложение на удаленный github-репозиторий которое имеет поддержку базы данных, в данном случае я использую Hibernate фреймворк. Обязательно ли устанавливать человеку который хочет протестировать моё приложение сервер баз данных PostgreSQL, восстанавливать из дампа все таблицы которые у меня есть в бд или это можно как-то избежать, если да то как?

Answer (score 2):

Да, у человека, который захочет поднять сервер из исходников должен быть установлен Postgres, в нём должна быть создана база и в ней должны быть таблицы и данные, которые необходимы для корректной работы.

Облегчить процесс можно несколькими способами.

1. Например использовать что-то типа `flyway` для того, чтобы при старте сервера в первый раз были выполнены SQL скрипты, которые создадут таблицы и наполнят их данными.
2. Использовать `Docker`, чтобы установить `Postgres`. Однако тут надо сам докер устанавливать.
3. Предоставить вместе с кодом конфигурацию, которая будет использовать не `Postgers`, но какую-то `in-memory` БД. Вроде бы `h2` для спринга подойдёт. Но также надо убедиться, что для этой конфигурации запуска будут созданы необходимые таблицы и они наполнены данными.